# How to store monthly data in a sharepoint list, from now until forever?

Tags: sharepoint, database-design, sharepoint-list

I need to store data every month for various programs in a sharepoint list. Each of 48 programs needs a "confirmed on" and "Confirmed by" data for every month, from now until forever.

Here's the issues I see

1. If I try to store it in one giant flat table, I'll have to create all of the months in advance, and it will cause problems when it reaches the end of the table. This is a government system, so whatever I build here has to last for 10+ years at a minimum.
2. If I have a new list created for each month, it will make putting together the summary reports, like "Show me the data for the past two years for program X," into a nightmare of union queries.
3. If I store the monthly data for each program in its own list, I will encounter the same issue of running out of data fields, and making a summary view will be a nightmare (Problems of #1 and #2).

This is at the bleeding edge of what I understand of databases so I would really apprecaite any advice on where to get started in the structure of such data storage.

Comment: SharePoint isn't an ideal 10yr solution for this but if that's the requirement & the list will truly only be written to once/month & then used going forward for reporting I would (and have in many Fed/DOD solutions) use a single list with 5 fields - Program Name (Single Line of Text, Choice or Lookup), MonthYear (Single Line of Text), Confirmed On (DateTime), Confirmed By (User) & `the data` stored as JSON (or even XML) in a Multiple Lines of Text field. Filtering & aggregation would be easy & creating BI reports from the data would be as simple as parsing the JSON/XML stored for each.

Comment: That... sounds like a solution. I understood about 1/3 of it. I know that multiple points of data can be stored in one data field, but as for the "how" I wouldn't even know where to begin. It involves visual basic to write the field as "Oldfieldvalue + New text value" right?